# Отложенная загрузка Div

Tags: javascript, ajax, joomla

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать отложенную загрузку элементов при прокрутке страницы.
К примеру есть

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="item">Item_1</div>
   <div class="item">Item_2</div>
   <div class="item">Item_3</div>
   <div class="item">Item_4</div>
   ...
   ...
   <div class="item">Item_101</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы, например, при загрузке странице загружались 10 элементов, и далее по 10 по мере прокрутке.

Как реализовать пагинацию в моем случае я не знаю. Подскажите как можно автоматически подгружать по 10 контейнеров, возможно есть несложное решение.  Спасибо!

Comment: Реализация очень сильно зависит от стэка разработки.
Вам непонятен принцип, или хотите уже (почти) готовое решение?

Comment: @АлександрКоноплян я находил готовые решения для отложенной загрузки изображений, но те, которые решения, которые я находил для отложенной загрузки элементов у меня почему-то не работали. Разумеется принцип мне не понятен, так как не владею темой вообще. Надеялся на то, что существует готовое решение. Возможно есть скрипты которые можно привязать к id или классу, или возможно к элементам <ul> <li>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот примерный код реализации: ([Тут код для функции elementInViewport](https://gist.github.com/daydarkln/95c4952727763de62be83cc0d6e7a966))

```
let template = [
  '<div class="item">Item_1</div>',
  '<div class="item">Item_2</div>',
  '<div class="item">Item_3</div>',
  '<div class="item">Item_4</div>',
  ...
  '<div class="item">Item_101</div>'
]

function appendItems() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('.container').append(template[i]);
  }

  template = template.splice(10, 101)
}

appendItems()

$(window).scroll(function() {
  const $last = $('.container .item').last()
  elementInViewport($last) ? appendItems() : true
})
```

Что тут происходит:

1. Задается массив с элементами, которые нужно добавить
2. Выводятся первые 10
3. Если последний элемент находится внутри видимой области экрана, выводится еще 10 и т.д.

Держи [ссылку](https://codepen.io/daydarkez/pen/qMNMmQ)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я извиняюсь, если не затруднит не могли бы Вы показать работу в песочнице. Так как у меня не работает, видимо что то делаю не так!

Comment: @Ivan Добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо! не мог понять, почему не работает Ваш вариант у меня на сайте, пока не вспомнил что у меня в CMS скрипты инициализируются, через 'jQuery(document).ready(function($) {' . Все заработало.  Но к сожалению адаптировать решение под свои нужды не вышло. Так как вопросе я указал схематически html на выходе. А на деле блоки имеют более сложную структуру выводятся посредством php с набором определенных опций: отображение аватара, описания, имени, ссылки на профиль...Не стал загромождать кодом и надеялся получить решение привязанное к id или через class блоков.

Comment: Для того, чтобы передать переменные в js, нужны более обширные знания, которых у меня к сожалению нет :). Но в любом случае Ваш вариант рабочий, возможно кому-то пригодится. Спасибо за помощь!